# Vectorize for routine using numpy.roll

Tags: python, numpy, vectorization

How can I vectorize the following code?

```
tlngth=20
sp_array = np.zeros((tlngth,tlngth))
sp = np.arange(0,tlngth)

for i in range(tlngth):
    sp_array[i] = np.roll(sp,i)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are essentially trying to build a Toeplitz matrix. There is a function for that:

```
import scipy.linalg
tlngth = 5
sp_array = scipy.linalg.toeplitz(np.roll(np.arange(tlngth - 1, -1, -1), 1),
                                 np.arange(tlngth))
#array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4],
#       [4, 0, 1, 2, 3],
#       [3, 4, 0, 1, 2],
#       [2, 3, 4, 0, 1],
#       [1, 2, 3, 4, 0]])
```

Comment: ...it seems like the circulant function does the job..but you have been of lots of help